# Fabricjs triangle management

Tags: fabricjs

How it's possible from three `left` and `top` make correct triangle with fabricjs. I have tried to do something with `width` and `height`, but result wasn't what expected.
Example: we have [{left:50,top:50},{left:40,top:60},{left:60,top:60}], how can we create a triangle with that values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var p1 = {left:50,top:50}; var p2 = {left:40,top:60}; var p3 = {left:60,top:60};
var shape = new fabric.Polygon([{x:p1.left, y:p1.top},{x:p2.left, y:p2.top},{x:p3.left, y:p3.top}]);
canvas.add(shape);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width="500" height="400" style="border:#000 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

You can create a fabric.Polygon([array of points...]);

every point must have 'x' and 'y' property.

Comment: That looks to work, thanks allot, i will test as soon as possible.

Comment: @GoncharDenys if it worked please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To create a triangle in fabric you don't set the three vertices. To create a triangle that way you should look into the [polygons](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Polygon.html) or [polylines](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Polyline.html). To create an actual [triangle](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Triangle.html) object you want to do something like this:

```
var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 20, height: 30, fill: 'blue', left: 50, top: 50
});
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdxw2971/1/).

Edit: In setting the position (`top`, `left`), these are relative to the `originX` and `originY` properties.

Comment: As i said, i need to give 3 locs to create triangle.

Answer (score 1):

The above code can be simplized to:

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var p1 = {x:50,y:50}, p2 = {x:40,y:60}, p3 = {x:60,y:60};
var shape = new fabric.Polygon([p1, p2, p3]);
canvas.add(shape);
```